# Can't create foreign key on mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, mysql-error-1005

When I try this

```
ALTER TABLE Comp_Entry
ADD FOREIGN KEY(CompetitionID) REFERENCES Comp__Competition(CompetitionID)
```

I get this error

```
#1005 - Can't create table 'chris_db.#sql-1464b_66' (errno: 150) (<a href="server_engines.php?engine=InnoDB&amp;page=Status&amp;token=7a7f690fbd1413e74979d79fa9044fb0">Details...</a>)
```

My `Comp_Competition` table has `CompetitionID` set as the primary key. Is anyone familiar with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your Comp_Entry table needs an existing index for CompetitionID. Also, your command has a double `__` characters in the name for table Comp__Competition, but in your explanation you have only one. Which one is right?

Answer (score 0):

Because there is data in your table which does not feet to your constraint (for example nonexistent keys)

try to make

```
     select * from Comp_Entry where CompetitionID not in 
        (select distinct CompetitionID from Comp__Competition)
```